# Network Manager causing duplicate routes

Tags: routing, networkmanager

I am using nmtui to create a network with multiple IP addresses on a single interface.  The problem is that it creates a separate duplicate route for each.  This is on AlmaLinux 8.7

ip route shows this...

```
default via 120.120.120.97 dev eno1 proto static metric 100 
10.1.1.0/24 via 10.1.2.1 dev eno2 proto static metric 101 
10.1.2.0/24 dev eno2 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.2.36 metric 101 
120.120.120.96/27 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 120.120.120.123 metric 100 
120.120.120.96/27 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 120.120.120.117 metric 100 
120.120.120.96/27 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 120.120.120.115 metric 100 
120.120.120.96/27 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 120.120.120.116 metric 100 
120.120.120.96/27 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 120.120.120.118 metric 100 
120.120.120.96/27 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 120.120.120.119 metric 100 
120.120.120.96/27 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 120.120.120.120 metric 100 
120.120.120.96/27 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 120.120.120.121 metric 100 
120.120.120.96/27 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 120.120.120.122 metric 100 
120.120.120.96/27 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 120.120.120.111 metric 100 
120.120.120.96/27 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 120.120.120.112 metric 100 
120.120.120.96/27 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 120.120.120.113 metric 100 
120.120.120.96/27 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 120.120.120.114 metric 100
```

And that kind of makes sense but when I just run route I see this which is the one bothering me.

```
 > route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno1
10.1.1.0        apolloback.delt 255.255.255.0   UG    101    0        0 eno2
10.1.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eno2
120.120.120.96    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     100    0        0 eno1
120.120.120.96    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     100    0        0 eno1
120.120.120.96    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     100    0        0 eno1
120.120.120.96    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     100    0        0 eno1
120.120.120.96    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     100    0        0 eno1
120.120.120.96    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     100    0        0 eno1
120.120.120.96    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     100    0        0 eno1
120.120.120.96    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     100    0        0 eno1
120.120.120.96    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     100    0        0 eno1
120.120.120.96    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     100    0        0 eno1
120.120.120.96    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     100    0        0 eno1
120.120.120.96    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     100    0        0 eno1
120.120.120.96    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     100    0        0 eno1
```

Everything seems to be working properly but I have never before seen all those identical routes.   Should I be worried?  How can I fix it or should I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not worry, it's the same route table entries as `ip route` shows, just not displaying the src addr.

`route` isn't the most up-to-date tool, so use `ip route` to see the full truth :-)